# Why is $\hat y = y$ for me?

Tags: linear-regression

Assume a linear regression model $y=X\beta + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2I)$ and $\hat y=Xb$ where $b=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$. Besides $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the linear projection from the response space to the span of $X$, i.e., $\hat y=Hy$.

Now I have a really weird question.

If $\hat y=Hy$ then
\begin{align}
\hat y =& HX\beta + \epsilon \\
\hat y =& X\underbrace{(X'X)^{-1}X'X}_{\text{I}}\beta + \epsilon \\
\hat y =& X\beta + \epsilon \\
\hat y =& y
\end{align}

What's wrong here?

Comment: I think $H$ must be applied also on $\epsilon$ ad $H \epsilon=0$ for the hp. of uncorrelation between $\epsilon$ and $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not multiplying the error term. It should be like that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\widehat{\mathbf{y}} & = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}+ \mathbf{H} \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I must be blind ... Thanks!

Comment: All we are making this kind of mistakes ;)